# jquery detect ::after css selector click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a css class with a ::after selector , and  when a user click on the element that have this class i want to show an alert. but i don't know why its not working .
this is my code :

css :

```
.flatpickr-time.time24hr :first-child:after {
    content: 'Valider';
    background: #BB0A30;
    font-family: 'audditype-bold';
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 50px 8px 50px;
    left: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
}
```

js:

```
$('.flatpickr-time.time24hr :first-child:after').click(function(){


alert('hello test')


});
```

so the purpose here is to show an alert when clicking on the content 'valider'

Answer (score 1):

It's a little messy, but this can be achieved by checking *where* the pointer was when the click event occurred.

If the pointer is outside the bounds of the control then we assume it was the ':after' psuedoelement that was clicked.

Here's a snippet that shows this working:

```js
$('.flatpickr-time.time24hr :first-child').click(function(e) {
  let ctl = $('.flatpickr-time.time24hr :first-child');
  
  if (e.offsetX > ctl.width() || e.offsetY > ctl.height()) {
    console.log('test');
  }
});
```

```css
.flatpickr-time.time24hr :first-child:after {
    content: 'Valider';
    background: #BB0A30;
    font-family: 'audditype-bold';
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 50px 8px 50px;
    left: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flatpickr-time time24hr">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Note: This will only work if the `:after` pseudo element does actually occur further to the right, or lower, than the primary element.  If it occurs before it then it will not work.

Second note: This will also work for `:before` pseudo elements.  It's not restricted to `:after` only, which may or may not be desirable.